# How do I reply to a user on Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I run a Bitbucket repo and got an email today from a user reporting an error message:

```
John Doe <notifications-noreply@bitbucket.org>

2:17 PM (8 hours ago)

to me
John Doe sent you a message on Bitbucket:

Hi, I can't build svg2xml-dev from scratch. After a fix in pom.xml:

-            <artifactId>pdf2svg-dev</artifactId>
+            <artifactId>pdf2svg</artifactId>
```

How do I reply to this person (I have anonymised their name, but it had two components separated by whitespace)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replay with the bitbucket website.

1. Go to Bitbucket.org
2. Click to login (if you have not already do it)
3. After you are logged click to your avatar (You can find it in top right)
4. A pop down menu appears.
5. Click to inbox.
6. Click to message you are going to replay.
7. Enter your message.

Comment: Thank you! It's very easy when explained, but I couldn't find any docs that led straight there.